# How do I solve this equation with logical equivalence laws?

Tags: logical-operators, equivalence

The problem is :

Show that ¬ p → (q → r) and q → (p v r) are logically equivalent.

I'm having trouble proving this with the use of Logical Identities. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this can be proved like this.

```
 ~p --> (q --> r)   
 ~~p v (q --> r)    -- (p -->q = ~p v q)   --Implication law
 p v (~q v r)       -- (~ (~p) = p )       -- Double negation law
 ~q v (p v r)       -- (P ∨ (Q ∨ R) ≡ (P ∨ Q) ∨ R)  -- associativity Law
 q --> (p v r)                             -- Implication law
```

Comment: Hello thank you for this. Can you name what law you used in each step?

Comment: I have made edit, see the link U will get all the laws (http://www.cs.um.edu.mt/gordon.pace/Teaching/DiscreteMaths/Laws.pdf)